# Совместить php и html

Tags: php, html

Всем привет. Вопрос делаю проверку на логин. Хочу сделать что если человек авторизовался то вывел этот html код иначе другой html код.

```
if ($_SESSION['admin_auth']==1) ?><p>Авторизовался</p>

<?php;else 
        form_auth();

        ?>
```

Можно конечно вывести через echo но это сразу нет. Так как я буду выводить много таблиц и тд. Подскажите что можно сделать? Например товары через цикл вывожу так

```
<?php $categories=get_cat();
             foreach ($categories as $item):?>
             <tr>
              <td style="border-top:1px solid #a0a0a0; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;">
              <a href="index.php?view=cat&id=<?php echo $item['category']?>"><?php echo $item['name']?></a>
              </td>
             </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день!

В скрипте есть ошибки

```
   <?php if ($_SESSION['admin_auth']==1){ ?>
                <p>Авторизовался</p>
   <?php } else {
                form_auth();
         }
   ?>
```

Ну а так, не совсем понятен ваш вопрос...

P.S. Вы можете использовать и старый синтаксис (только исправьте ошибки), просто мне приятнее C подобный синтаксис

Comment: вот блин, я не думал что надо ставить фигурные ковычки, как бы была одна строка, спасибо! Работает. А то уже хотел подключать сторонний файл!